# Linker error with mysql.h in c programming

Tags: mysql, c

Hi I would like to solve how I can fix with linker error.
What I wanted to do is to include header file which is mysql.h from /usr/local/include.(I'm using mac book)

But when compiling the header file which is below, compiler says "Undefined symbols for architecture"

```
#include </usr/local/include/mysql.h>
```

I obviously installed mysql and connecter-c.

Please teach me how to fix it and why mysql.h is not included.

Best regards,

Comment: Did you install mysql or are you just using the header?

Comment: Headers are not enough as they normally only provide _declarations_ of functions, not their actual implementations.

Comment: have you tried to link to its library using -l flag?

Comment: It smells like you are linking a library for a different platform.

Comment: >Tiago Cunha 
I installed mysql and I want to use that function for database program.

>ForceBru 
So what should I do?I installed mysql and connecter and its function is in local file.

>Nguai al
Yes, but it doesn't work.

> LPs
different platform? Is that mean there are many mysql.h exist and I linked from wrong directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check the format in which you have included the header file.

```
#include </usr/local/include/mysql.h>
```

should be

```
#include "/usr/local/include/mysql.h"
```

the "<>" is used to include system header files. please use double quotes ("") to include user header files.